How to Create a Lead in Odoo 17 Using Only API Key for Authorization (No Session ID)
I'm trying to create a lead in Odoo 17 by sending a POST request with an API key in the Authorization header (Bearer <API_KEY>). However, I keep getting a "Session Expired" error unless I also include the session_id, which I want to avoid.
Is there a way to make this request work with just the API key, without needing the session ID?
request with postman
enter image description here

Where did you get the session_id?  IS IT expired?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Please [edit] your question to convert images into text, and use a [code block] for any code you have. Readers can then search the text or run the code to reproduce your issue.
